# Is this serial up-voting?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

This [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2776866/skippy-ps-im-a-woman) asked a question recently. This is that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834046/adding-objects-to-an-array). There were quite a few answers to it and the OP went ahead and upvoted it, thanking everybody for their time and effort. Soon after the OP asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834454/the-difference-between-this-and-the-class-name) and once there were a few answer, the OP did the same thing. Upvoted each answer and thanks every body for their time and effort.

While its good to see a user happy with the responses and upvoting the effort of every answer post, I fear that continuously upvoting so many answers, in such a short time, might trigger a serial upvoting scenario in this case. Though the intentions of the user are good, with no evil intentions, will this fall under the bracket of serial-upvoting? And if it does, what do we do, in such a case? Do we ask the user to not upvote like this(but vote is the user's choice and they can use it as per their wish and certainly this user doesn't seem to be gaming the system either).

*P.S:* I just wanted to know if this will trigger the serial upvoting algorithm or not, because if it does, then I would like to warn the OP regarding this, since there was no bad/evil intention of the OP to involve in serial upvoting as such and help the OP not get banned for serial voting.

Comment: Serial voting is reserved to voting against a _person_. This is not the same. It is also not particularly useful, however.

Comment: The OP did not upvote multiple posts of a specific user.

Comment: So this scenario does not fall under the bracket of serial up-voting? Then that's a good thing, as I feared that the OP might get banned for serially-upvoting many answers, without any evil intentions. Just had to make sure about this.

Comment: Not really sure why people are disagreeing with the question, when its just asking(clarifying) something and not proposing something.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear - are you asking whether it **would** trigger the serial upvoting algorithm, or whether it **should**? Since you say you're not proposing something, I guess it's the prior - maybe people assume the latter and thus downvote, and you can downvote discussions if you don't think they're useful or for some other reasons).

Comment: If you read the second para of my question, you would know that I never proposed that it should trigger a serial upvoting algorithm here. I just wanted to know if this falls under that bracket, and if it I did, how could I warn the OP from doing it, because the OP never has any bad/evil intentions regarding this. I just wanted to help the OP and nothing else.

Comment: my rule of thumb: upvote all good answers and accept the one who works for me

Comment: @Dirty-flow - That's a good rule!:) But how is it related to my question?

Comment: the OP did the same: he thinks all answers are good and has upvoted them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think this is serial up-voting, unless they're *also* going through the post history of the people who answer their questions and up-voting other stuff those people have posted.

This sounds like someone who is trying to encourage lots of responses to their questions by responding positively to all the answers. Unless they're up-voting patently dumb replies I can only see that as a good thing.